# count mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have got a table with ID's:

```
Id      Name
==================
1       kim
2       james
2       kim
1       kim
1       james
2       james
```

And I want to create a table with count Id=1 like this:

```
james 1
kim   1
```

or

```
james     kim
=================
1         1
```

please help me

Comment: `SELECT distinct id, name FROM table WHERE id = 1`

Comment: Your counts don't seem to match the data in your table.

Comment: sorry Tim mymistake
james 1
kim     2

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
    Name,
    COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM yourTable
WHERE Id = 1
GROUP BY
    Id,
    Name
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT name, count(1)
FROM table_name
WHERE id = 1
GROUP BY name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use distinct  -- SELECT distinct id, name FROM table WHERE id = 1

Comment: This won't include the counts, you need to aggregate for that.